# How to filter within a subgroup (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, filter, time-series

here is my problem:

You will find below a Pandas DataFrame, I would like to groupby Date and then filtering within the subgroups, but I have a lot of difficulties in doing it (spent 3 hours on this and I haven't find any solution).

This is what I am looking for : 
I first have to group everything by date, then sort each score from the max to the lower (in each subgroup) and then select the two best scores but they have to be from different countries. 
(For example, if the two best are from the same country then we select the higher score with a country different from the first).

This is the DataFrame :

```
Date  Name     Score  Country
2012  Paul      65     France
2012  Silvia    81     Italy
2012  David     80     UK
2012  Alphonse  46     France
2012  Giovanni  82     Italy 
2012  Britney   53     UK
2013  Paul      32     France 
2013  Silvia    59     Italy 
2013  David     92     UK
2013  Alphonse  68     France
2013  Giovanni  23     Italy
2013  Britney   78     UK
2014  Paul      46     France 
2014  Silvia    87     Italy 
2014  David     89     UK
2014  Alphonse  76     France 
2014  Giovanni  53     Italy
2014  Britney   90     UK
```

The Result I am looking for is something like this :

```
Date  Name     Score  Country
2012  Giovanni  82     Italy 
2012  David     80     UK
2013  David     92     UK
2013  Alphonse  68     France
2014  Britney   90     UK
2014  Silvia    87     Italy
```

Here is the code that I started :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Date':["2012","2012","2012","2012","2012","2012","2013","2013","2013","2013","2013","2013","2014","2014","2014","2014","2014","2014"],
     'Name': ["Paul", "Silvia","David","Alphone", "Giovanni", "Britney","Paul", "Silvia","David","Alphone", "Giovanni", "Britney","Paul", "Silvia","David","Alphone", "Giovanni", "Britney"],
     'Score': [65, 81, 80, 46, 82, 53,32,59,92,68,23,78,46,87,89,76,53,90],
     "Country":["France","Italy","UK","France","Italy","UK","France","Italy","UK","France","Italy","UK","France","Italy","UK","France","Italy","UK"]})

df = df.set_index('Name').groupby('Date')["Score","Country"].apply(lambda _df: _df.sort_values(["Score"],ascending=False))
```

And this is what I have :

[image]

But as you can see for example in 2012, the two best scores are from the same country (Italy), so what I still have to do is : 
1. Select the max per country for each year
2. Select only two best scores (and the countries have to be different).

I will be really thankful for that because I really don't know how to do it. 
If somebody has some ideas on that, please share it :)

PS : please don't hesitate to tell me if it wasn't clear enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) first by 2 columns, then remove duplicates by 2 columns by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and last select top values per groups by [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
df1 = (df.sort_values(['Date','Score'], ascending=[True, False])
         .drop_duplicates(['Date','Country'])
         .groupby('Date')
         .head(2))
print (df1)
    Date      Name  Score Country
4   2012  Giovanni     82   Italy
2   2012     David     80      UK
8   2013     David     92      UK
9   2013  Alphonse     68  France
17  2014   Britney     90      UK
13  2014    Silvia     87   Italy
```